# How to show output in console when writing an RMarkdown notebook?

Tags: r, console, output, r-markdown

I have a simple question, and I think I'm just not looking in the right place, or RStudio is not acting as expected. **I'd like to know if there is an option to output the results of all my markdown code chunks to go to the plots window or the console.**

I'm starting to use R Notebooks to write in R Markdown. Say I type the command

```
head(cars)
```

into my .Rmd document. I press Ctrl + Enter, and the line is run. Up pops the first 6 lines of the cars dataframe into my script. I see that the line has been run in the console, but the output is not in the console.

**Why does this bug me?** Sometimes my code chunks are long. Then, I have to annoyingly scroll to the end of the chunk to see my results. Or, I type head(car), run the line, then decide I want to see tail(car) and run that line. In the console, I'd be able to see both results (head and tail of the dataframe) but in the .Rmd file, because I didn't run them both at once, the results of my "head" call disappear. These seem like small problems but when they happen over and over it's frustrating! I know that if I type directly into the console, I can see the results, but this interrupts my workflow.

**What I've tried:** Besides googling, I've gone into RStudio --> tools --> R Markdown, and made sure that the option "show output inline for all markdown documents" is unchecked - doesn't make a difference.

Am I missing an option here? I'm using **R Studio Version 1.0.136**.

Thanks!

Here is the code (using an .Rmd notebook file)

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---


```{r}
# run just this line
head(cars)

# run just this line
tail(cars)

# Both show up below (here in the file) but do not go to console
```
````

And a screenshot: [image: output does not go to console]

Comment: Can you copy and paste here your code?

Comment: It's pretty basic, but here it is, plus a screenshot! See how the calls, executed from the notebook, do not produce output in the console?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the [official website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#creating_a_notebook) (emphasis by me):

> By default, RStudio enables inline output (notebook mode) on all R Markdown documents, so you can interact with any R Markdown document as though it were a notebook. If you have a document with which you prefer to use the traditional console method of interaction, **you can disable notebook mode by clicking the gear in the editor toolbar and choosing *Chunk Output in Console***.

This sets the `chunk_output_type` option in the YAML front-matter of your R Markdown document to `console`:

```
---
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Adding those lines to the YAML front-matter without clicking any GUI option will of course lead to the same result.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I swear I've tried this option before and it didn't work... but maybe updating RStudio worked and I hadn't tried it again after updating. Thanks @cadair, I will be much happier now!

Comment: Hmm... after a day of trying this, I've noticed that it seems to often "default" back to the output appearing inline, even within the same session. Strange.

Comment: I feel like R Studio is becoming slightly more like Apple who is constantly forcing their evolving product and design choices on you. I can't help but wonder if it's the tidyverse influence.

Comment: The setting seems to flip from "Chunk Output in Console" to "Chunk Output Inline"  whenever I save the RNotebook

Comment: Is there a line of code you can put in that does this? It is annoying having to manually do it every time. Also sharing code with people not used to R you have to tell them what to do.

Comment: I realised myself it is an option in the setup
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console

Comment: When I change the `chunk_output_type` to `console`, the notebook's HTML output never gets updated. I am on version `1.3.1056`. Any lead why?

Comment: Could you define "GUI options" to trigger this setting? Like do I have to click knit just for this to register? Are there any other triggers that don't try to do anything except load the doc settings?

Answer (score 21):

Under Options in Tools, choose the options for R Markdown, change the tick for "Show output inline...." to "untick".
Good luck!

Comment: I think both this and @cadair answers are complimentary.  My understanding is that this answer changes the default behavior for all new rmd docs, while cadair's will only change the chunk output for a specific document you are currently editing.