# Debugging an RMarkdown file from the command line

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to take an Rmarkdown file written by someone else and run it from the command line (not RStudio) using

```
Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render("input.Rmd")'
```

Execution continues along printing things like this to my console as it processes each chunk:

```
label: readDataFiles (with options) 
List of 1
 $ error: logi TRUE

  |..............                                                   |  22%
  ordinary text without R code
```

However, a chunk is failing and execution stops. I believe it is because a path passed to a function is not valid. So I tried to add a new chunk that displays the value of this path **to my console**:

````
``` {r thePath, eval=True}
path
```
````

However I just see the output

```
label: thePath (with options) 
List of 1
 $ eval: logi TRUE
```

The value of the `path` variable is not visible. And I do not get out an HTML file to look at because the overall knitting process fails. How can I debug this in my console?

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861570/145504) with no success.

Comment: Could you not use Rstudio?

Comment: dumb idea  create a log file  by writing in the chunk `my_log <- file("log.log")` and `cat(path, file = my_log)` then look for that file with the path info

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stop(path)` to kill the compile with an error message showing you the path.  For example, put this in your `.Rmd` file:

````
```{r}
path <- "c:/wrong/path"
stop("path=",path)
```
````

This is what I see when I run this file on the command line:

```
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 19-21 (untitled.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : path=c:/wrong/path
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted
```

As long as you put this in the file ahead of the actual error that is killing your compile, you'll see it.

Edited to add:  you can also use `warning()` or `message()` (as @sindri_baldur mentioned) for this, but for those you need to change the chunk default to `warning=FALSE` or `message=FALSE` respectively so the message goes to `stderr` and shows up in the console.